# How do I get utility lines marked on my property?

Tags: safety, lawn, precautions

In Michigan, there is a service called Miss Dig for identifying buried utility lines. We've just moved from Michigan to New Hampshire, and we would like to know where our utility lines are buried. What service should I call?

Comment: It would perhaps be a good idea to edit the question to be less localized.  Then people can answer for different localities.

Comment: With the wider scope of the question this should probably become community wiki, there won't be one right answer now.

Comment: http://www.talgov.com/you/dig.cfm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

811 is the universal number for all US states.

Canada has different numbers.

[Listing here](http://www.call811.com/state-specific.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

A list of "Know Before You Dig" services, by state, is available here: [811 Website](http://www.call811.com/state-specific.aspx)

For New Hampshire, contact Dig Safe Systems, Inc.

Comment: Yup - in any state in the US, just dial 811 on your phone, they'll take your information and contact all of the companies that might have utilities in your area. It usually takes a few days for all of the utilities to come out and check, so be sure to leave yourself enough time.

Comment: And that list also includes Canadian provinces.

Comment: @Jared: At least in Florida, they have to be out within 24 hrs

Answer (score 2):

This question is really too localised, so this answer doesn't apply to all, but in Australia there's Dial Before You Dig on `1100`